# What is the approach to add MFA (TOTP based) for a .NET core project which is not using the ASP.NET Core Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I have a **.NET Core 6.0** api project that is **not** using ASP.NET Core Identity.

The authentication is performed using JWT:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options => ...                  
                    };
                });
```

Login controller returns the JWT token (containing the username) which is used by the client for subsequent endpoint requests.

At the controller/action level there is the `[Authorize]` tag that allows authenticated/authorized used to access the endpoint.

The username, password is stored in a custom Users table in SQL server database.

I recently added the concept of Roles by adding a new column Role to the above table and then in the Login endpoint I have stored the user's role into the JWT claims. Then at the respective endpoints am checking for the role like this: `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]`

This means concept of Role is not tightly coupled with ASP.NET Core Identity.

However based on this link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/mfa?view=aspnetcore-6.0) it looks like the MFA TOTP is tightly coupled with ASP.NET Core Identity. What is the approach to add MFA (TOTP based) for a .NET core project which is not using the ASP.NET Core Identity?

Comment: This is related with your identity provider. The asp.net core identity contains its own implement for the MFA. If your identity provider support MFA, you could just set it. If your identity provide doesn't support it. You need achieve it by yourself.

Comment: What is the mfa based on? For example - the JWT token verification is based on secret.